# Setting ns-cert-type server for OpenVPN using phpseclib

Tags: php, x509, openvpn, phpseclib

Since the documentation for phpseclib is very poor, I'm asking here if there is a way to set the `ns-cert-type` for a certificate whis this library.

Searching on the sources, I've found this:

```
        // the following OIDs are unsupported but we don't want them to give notices when calling saveX509().
        case 'id-pe-logotype': // http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3709.txt
        case 'entrustVersInfo':
        // http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287547
        case '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2': // szOID_ENROLL_CERTTYPE_EXTENSION
        case '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.1': // szOID_CERTSRV_CA_VERSION
        // "SET Secure Electronic Transaction Specification"
        // http://www.maithean.com/docs/set_bk3.pdf
        case '2.23.42.7.0': // id-set-hashedRootKey
            return true;
```

The interesting part I think is `szOID_ENROLL_CERTTYPE_EXTENSION`, but it seems to be unsupported :(

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
$x509->setExtension('netscape-cert-type', array('SSLServer'));
```

It works perfectly with OpenVPN!

Taken from the source:

```
// mapping is from <http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tech-notes/tn3.html>
$this->netscape_cert_type = array(
    'type'    => FILE_ASN1_TYPE_BIT_STRING,
    'mapping' => array(
        'SSLClient',
        'SSLServer',
        'Email',
        'ObjectSigning',
        'Reserved',
        'SSLCA',
        'EmailCA',
        'ObjectSigningCA'
    )
);
```